# Call a function from a class name using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have a table which have class name `Start_point` on tr. I want a method which should call on click by class not on click by attribute.

```
<tr class="Start_Point" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% yellow;">
<td>
<input type="checkbox">
</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>MaxFort School, Parwana Road</td>
<td>28.69178</td>
<td>77.10968</td>
<td>09:34:29</td>
<td>Start</td>
<td>
<input type="button" value="Edit">
<input type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)" value="Delete">
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your intentions are unclear.

Comment: First you need to use jQuery library and then use the class selector as follows. $(".Start_Point").click(function(){ .............. }

Comment: i have this library bt its not working u can see this at link

Answer (score 0):

Try using class selector of jquery

```
   $('.Start_Point').click(function(){


    });
```

Comment: class="Start_Point" missing in your html code i suppose

Comment: @AshishSrivastava: There's no markup or code in that fiddle that puts `Start_Point` on the rows!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
   $('.Start_Point').click(function(){
    // your code
   })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
    $(".Start_Point").click(function(){ alert("Your function"); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
$('.<className>').click(function(){
    alert("<Your enter code here>")
})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle rows which get the `Start_Point` class *later*, rather than not having it initially, you can use event delegation for that:

```
$("selector-for-the-table").on("click", ".Start_Point", function() {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking the functionality as this refer [this link (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/3vE6w/) I developed this have a look

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Start_Point").click(function(){
        console.log("called");
        alert("do want you want to do");
    });
 });
```